# How to access js Object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a script and where i get some objects and don't access them using some of my code's.
Say the output is- `response`.

**Objects:**

```
0 : Object
    created_time : "2010-08-24T06:21:00+0000"
    id : "some_id"
    name : "Name"
__proto__ :  Object
1 : Object
2 : Object
```

I want to access the `id`, but can't access it.

My Code:

```
response.id
```

But gives me `undefined`.

Comment: what is the name of the object? *something* `[0].id` is the best I can do

Comment: can you show the code on how you are trying to access it?

Comment: @JaromandaX, I update my Question.

Comment: @Nico, I added it to my question.

Comment: change *something* to *response* in my first comment, if that doesn't work, then you're not giving enough information

Comment: You have to iterate this because objects are in array if you want the first element then it will be `response[0].id`

Comment: @JaromandaX, Ha ha ha.. Its my typing mistake, cause i want both information and i ask for id and write name.

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yes it works now, But how can i iterate cause i have a lot of id there and i need to compare.

Comment: `forEach`, `for ... loop` are two options - there are many other Array methods that could be more useful depending on what you want to do with the id once you have it - the choice is all yours

Comment: Yes i use for and the problem is, i lost the nestes Objects.. Cause i use `for (var property in response) {  console.log(property) }`, gives me the number only.

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yes i make it, Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response` appears to be an array. There isn't a single `name` property to be accessed, but (presumably) one for each item in the array:

```
console.log(response[0].name);
console.log(response[1].name);
```

etc...

Comment: Can you please provide me the Iteration?? I want to do it in a loop.